# Make API using a different host in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

I'm new to nodejs and currently using `localhost` to run mock APIs.

index.js -

```
const express = require("express");
const api = require("./routes/api");
const app = express();

// Routes
app.use("/api", api); // route api
```

routes/api/index.js -

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/path-to-certain-resource", async (req, res) => {
 });
//...
router.post("/path-to-another-resource", async(req,res) => {
});
```

I need to create a new API using a predefined url - 
e.g. `https://example.com/api/v1/users`

How can I do this?

Comment: use Heroku cloud, go through tutorials for it. (search how to deploy nodejs server on heroku.)